# Nested relationships wagtail api

Tags: api, wagtail

I have the following data structure:

```
{"related_cases": [
    {
        "type": "related_case_block",
        "value": {
            "case": 13,
            "short_text": "Case 2 is related!"
        },
        "id": "3aec5efe-55dc-441f-aa5c-fbbb801d237a"
    }
]}
```

Related cases is a streamfield with blocks inside. Each block holds a reference to another case page. Which is 13 in this case.

I would like to include some fields from this case into the response, like this:

```
 {"related_cases": [
    {
        "type": "related_case_block",
        "value": {
            "case": {
                "id": 13,
                "title": "Case 2"
            },
            "short_text": "Case 2 is related!"
        },
        "id": "3aec5efe-55dc-441f-aa5c-fbbb801d237a"
    }
]}
```

Can anyone explain how I would accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've defined `related_case_block` as a subclass of `StructBlock`, you can override the `get_api_representation` method on that class:

```
class RelatedCaseBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    # ...
    def get_api_representation(self, value, context=None):
        return {
            'case': {
                'id': value['case'].id
                'title': value['case'].title
            },
            'short_text': value['short_text']
        }
```